# What is the relationship between Goodwillie calculus and derived deformation theory?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, deformation-theory, higher-algebra

[Goodwillie calculus](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Goodwillie+calculus) is a way of understanding a functor $F$ in terms of its Goodwillie tower, a tower whose limit approximates $F$, whose layers can be understood in terms of [stable](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stable+%28infinity%2C1%29-category) data. [Derived deformation theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/derived+deformation+theory) is a way of understanding objects $c$ of an $\infty$-category via a tower whose limit approximates $c$, and whose layers can be understood in terms of stable data.

**Question:** What is the relationship, more precisely, between Goodwillie calculus and derived deformation theory? For instance, is one a special case of the other?

Comment: At best, they might be instances of the same phenomenon, as are Postnikov towers. The key to DDT is that every square-zero extension can in a sense be delooped - see e.g. section 3.2 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.14594 .